# Scaling color intensity based on a range

Tags: c#, colors

I have a `Button` that I want to change its color from black to red depending on an integer that ranges from 0 to 4095.

When the number is 0 It should be black and while this number increases, say reachs 4095 it should be totaly red!

```
    ChangeColor(int num)
    {
        if(num== 0)
             lightRight.SetBackgroundColor(new Color(0,0,0));
        if(num> 4000)
            lightRight.SetBackgroundColor(new Color(255,0,0));
        //How to make a nice color that scales from 0 to 4095?
    }
```

Any idea how to approach this problem?

Comment: Assuming 8-bit RGB, what about `value/4095 * 255` for the red component?

Comment: Why down vote?! Show yourself shaky downvoter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what are your needs for intermediate colors. The RGB color is defined as 3 hex two digit numbers where #000000 is black and #FFFFFF is white.

First number refers to RED, second to GREEN and third to BLUE. So maximum number for each color is 255.

Therefore first choose desired RED color, let say this one is nice:

R: 219
G: 62
B: 0

Then calculate intermediate colors as follows, where x belongs to [0,4095]:

```
int r = 219 * (x / 4095f) 
int g = 62 * (x / 4095f) 
int b = 0  * (x / 4095f)
```

having those values apply the color to button background.

```
lightRight.SetBackgroundColor(new Color(r,g,b));
```

Answer (score 1):

Divide by 16 the integer value incremented by 1, you'll get a value between 1 and 256. Decrement this value by 1, and use that to calculate the different RGB components

Using your code snippet:

```
ChangeColor(int num)
{
    // num being between 0 and 4095, get a value between 0 and 255
    int red = ((num + 1) / 16 ) - 1;
    lightRight.SetBackgroundColor(new Color(red,0,0));
}
```

You'll have to deal with rounding and possible `-1` value, but you get the point...

Comment: if your dividing by 16 you could just bitshift `(num + 1)>>4` ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
int myInt; //The value that changes from 0 to 4095.
float red = myInt/4095.0;;
float green = 0;
float blue = 0;

Color myColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
```

Comment: Would not this output broader color spectrum than just from black to red ?

Comment: As it was (I edited it), it would produce a gradient from white to red. As it stands now, it produces a gradient from black to red as myInt goes from 0 to 4095.

The Color (1,1,1) (using the float constructor) is white. When the blue and green components decreased equally and red was left at 1 the color gradually changes from white to red.

In the new code the starting Color is (0,0,0), (i.e. black) and the red component gradually increase changing the color from black to red.